# uniformly bounded on compact set

Tags: set-valued-analysis

Let $F:\Omega\to 2^X\setminus\emptyset$, $\Omega$ is compact. If $F$ has bounded values then they are uniformly bounded. Please help me prove this! Thanks!

Comment: You have some continuity for $F$, I suppose. And bounded? What is $X$?

Comment: Welcome. If you've mentioned the details of your attempt, it'd be helpful for both you and the people who are gonna help you.

Comment: $X$ is a Banach space. $\Omega$ is a subset of a Banach space $Y$, $\Omega\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: I read Multivalued Diffential Equations (Klaus Deimlin), in p.6. On the 6th line from the bottom, the write "If $F$ has bounded values then they are uniformly bounded, since $\Omega$ is compact."

Answer (score 1):

A crucial assumption is missing from the question, as martini said. Quoting from the book:

> ... we have an $(\epsilon-\delta)$ usc $F:\Omega\to 2^X\setminus \varnothing$ with closed convex values.

Definition 1.2 on the same page explains the meaning of  "$(\epsilon-\delta)$ usc":  to every $\omega_0\in\Omega $ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta=\delta(\omega_0,\epsilon)>0$ such that $F(\omega)\subset F(\omega_0)+B_\epsilon(0)$ on $B_\delta(\omega_0)\cap \Omega$.

Now that the right assumptions are in place, the proof is easy. Let $\epsilon=1$. The sets $\{B_\delta(\omega_0): \delta=\delta(\omega_0,\epsilon), \omega_0\in\Omega\}$ form an open cover of $\Omega$. Pick a finite subcover, indexed by $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_N$. Let $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^N F(\omega_i)+B_1(0)$; this is a bounded set, and it contains $F(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

(The part about having closed convex values does not come into play here.)